# Замена строк файла регулярным выражением

Tags: php

PHP 8.1.

Есть ли функции для поиска и замены подстрок в файле регулярными выражениями без чтения всего файла в оперативную память?  Файлы очень большие.

Comment: Нет таких функций.

Comment: Что мешает вам читать файл построчно и производить замены?

Comment: какие инструменты для построчного чтения и замены наиболее быстрые? Буду признателен за конкретный пример кода.